# Messaging queue with a client behind a https proxy

Tags: java, messaging

Any ideas on how to implement messaging on a queue between a server and an external client.  The client will connect via https proxy.  This needs to be secure.

We already have instances of ActiveMQ which comes with WebSockets. Quick hacks using this have been a little awkward. I'm also aware that Spring has a SockJS implementation both server and client which is do-able.

Question is - are we too narrow in our thinking? Feels like a problem that's been solved already, so can anyone point at a solution and say how well it works?